Firebase: Service messaging is not available
I need to get notifications from Firebase, but I'm facing a problem and I can't find any answer for it:
Uncaught Error: Service messaging is not available

Package.json:
{
  "name": "sookler",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^2.17.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@googlemaps/react-wrapper": "^1.1.35",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.1",
    "@lottiefiles/react-lottie-player": "^3.5.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.1",
    "@mui/lab": "5.0.0-alpha.137",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.2",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.12.0",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.14.1",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.10.2",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.10.2",
    "@react-oauth/google": "^0.11.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "compressorjs": "^1.2.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "firebase": "^9.23.0",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "framer-motion": "^10.15.0",
    "google-maps-react": "^2.0.6",
    "i18next": "^23.4.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.4",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "mui-one-time-password-input": "^1.2.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-helmet-async": "^1.3.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.45.2",
    "react-i18next": "^13.0.3",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.2.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.23",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.2",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.3",
    "react-verification-code-input": "^1.2.9",
    "styled-components": "^6.0.5",
    "swiper": "^8.4.7",
    "yup": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.8",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  }
}

firebaseInit.js:
import "firebase/compat/messaging";
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCSVOuA-4DT-NGyFXZ5IG13Q7gLpFoMa6Q",
  authDomain: "sookler-plus-a1ef1.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "sookler-plus-a1ef1",
  storageBucket: "sookler-plus-a1ef1.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "868289122853",
  appId: "1:868289122853:web:803612b64dcb557e04e5cc",
  measurementId: "G-53P05PKSY1"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

const publicKey = "BG-qtMNhGMcses3C612MtjKQZ9cbonJMI6pbQ4ec47jxtAjaQHepQvL45cANy_18B3I1xRP5WEi7mMvbCc3EnW0";

export const getFirebaseToken = async () => {
  let currentToken = null;
  try {
    currentToken = await messaging.getToken({ vapidKey: publicKey });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("An error occurred while retrieving token. ", error);
  }
  return currentToken;
};

export const onMessageListener = () =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
      resolve(payload);
    });
  });

firebase-messaging-sw.js:
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
// Scripts for firebase and firebase messaging

importScripts(
  "xxx://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app-compat.js"
);
importScripts(
  "xxx://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js"
);


console.log("Firebase service worker script loaded"); 

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCSVOuA-4DT-NGyFXZ5IG13Q7gLpFoMa6Q",
  authDomain: "sookler-plus-a1ef1.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "sookler-plus-a1ef1",
  storageBucket: "sookler-plus-a1ef1.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "868289122853",
  appId: "1:868289122853:web:803612b64dcb557e04e5cc",
  measurementId: "G-53P05PKSY1"
};
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Retrieve firebase messaging
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

self.addEventListener("notificationclick", function (event) {
  event.notification.close();
  const openWindowPromise = clients.openWindow("xxx://localhost:5173"); // Fill in the URL 'notifications page' to open, ex: xxx://XXX.com/my-notifications
  event.waitUntil(openWindowPromise);
});

self.addEventListener("push", function (event) {
  debugger;
  console.log('eventeee: ', event)
  const payload = event.data.json();
  const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.notification.body,
    icon: "./favicon.ico", // Fill in the path to the icon
    sound: "PATH_TO_SOUND", // Fill in the path to the sound file
    dir: "auto",
  };

  // Check if any clients are currently visible (app is open)
  const areClientsVisible = clients
    .matchAll({
      type: "window",
      includeUncontrolled: true,
    })
    .then(function (clientList) {
      for (let i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
        if (clientList[i].visibilityState === "visible") {
          return true; // At least one client is visible
        }
      }
      return false; // No visible clients
    });

  // Close any existing notifications
  self.registration.getNotifications().then(function (notifications) {
    console.log('notifications: ', notifications)
    notifications.forEach(function (notification) {
      notification.close();
    });
  });

  // Show the notification only if no clients are visible
  event.waitUntil(
    areClientsVisible.then(function (visible) {
      if (!visible) {
        return self.registration.showNotification(
          notificationTitle,
          notificationOptions
        );
      }
    })
  );
});

